# MySQL Relevance Ordering

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work out the best way to order search results, they need to be ordered as below, but it doesn't appear to work.

Could this be because the column rating is being selected but the user is not filling in an input named rating?

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
   $address = trim($_POST['address']);
   $street = trim($_POST['street']);
   $city = trim($_POST['city']);
   $county = trim($_POST['county']);

   if($lname==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Last Name."; 
   }elseif($address=""){
       $error[] = "Provide House Number/Name.";
   }elseif($street==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Street.";
   }elseif($city==""){
       $error[] = "Provide City.";
   }elseif($county==""){
       $error[] = "Provide County.";
   }else{
       try{
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
           FROM clients
           WHERE  lname  like :lname
           AND   address like :address
           AND   street  like :street
           AND   city    like :city
           AND   county  like :county
           ORDER BY rating 
           WHEN rating like 'badabusive' THEN 0
           WHEN rating like 'badnopay' THEN 1
           WHEN rating like 'cautionlate' THEN 2
           WHEN rating like 'cautiondiscount' THEN 3
           WHEN rating like 'cautionextra' THEN 4
           WHEN rating like 'good' THEN 5
           END, rating");

           $stmt->execute(array("lname"  => empty($lname) ? '%' : '%'. $lname .'%',
           "address" => empty($address) ? '%' : '%'. $address .'%',
           "street"  => empty($street) ? '%' : '%'. $street .'%',
           "city"    => empty($city) ? '%' : '%'. $city .'%',
           "county"  => empty($county) ? '%' : '%'. $county .'%'));

    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(!$userRow){                  
                     if($user->reportsearch($id,$lname,$address,$street,$city,$county)){
                          $user->redirect('./results.php?new='.$lname.$street);
                      }
                }else{
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'badnopay'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?badnopay='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautionextra'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?cautionextra='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautiondiscount'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?cautiondiscount='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautionlate'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?cautionlate='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'good'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?good='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                    if($userRow['rating'] == 'badabusive'){
                        $user->redirect('./results.php?badabusive='.$lname.$street);
                    }
                }
            }
        catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

I want the results to be shown in this order, so  if I have multiple results which have different ratings then I want them to show as ordered.

It is reloading page on submit and not showing the results page as it normally should.

Comment: your missing the term `CASE`

Comment: Not a duplicate, Thanks for the `CASE` I had missed that but now it only reloads the page

Comment: Not anymore, but it still wasn't a duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your script.

1. The query, the when after the order is incorrect
2. You will have to print out the url's you want, redirect is possible, but it will redirect you to the first row only (or first result)
3. You have a rating of badshort in your data, this will result to null, because you don't have a rule for 'badshort' to become a value.

The complete script to test without post would become:

```
<?php
$lname = 'something';
$address = 'something1';
$street = 'something2';
$city = 'something3';
$county = 'something4';

try{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, case 
WHEN rating like 'badabusive' THEN 0 
WHEN rating like 'badnopay' THEN 1 
WHEN rating like 'cautionlate' THEN 2 
WHEN rating like 'cautiondiscount' THEN 3 
WHEN rating like 'cautionextra' THEN 4 
WHEN rating like 'good' THEN 5 
END as ratingval FROM clients 
WHERE  
lname  like :lname and
address  like :address and
street  like :street and
city  like :city and
county  like :county
order by ratingval");

$stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $address);
$stmt->bindParam(':street', $street);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $city);
$stmt->bindParam(':county', $county);

$stmt->execute();

$userRow = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(!$userRow){
print "nothing found";
}
else
{
foreach ($userRow as $result) {
echo $result[lname] . " " . $result[ratingval]. "<br>";
}
}
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: could you post the error if any?

Comment: There is no error, it just refreshes the search page as before

Comment: could you try it in your database manager or phpmyadmin

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':lname AND address like :address AND street like :street AND city like' at line 8

Comment: I edited the query, could you test again in your db admin

Comment: It's showing results in phpmyadmin but not on page, it was working fine before adding the order.

Comment: post the one that was working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94221/discussion-between-davejal-and-saucedapples).

Comment: You are not adding appropriate `%` wildcards to the parameter values you are binding. Without this, this might a well be `=`

Comment: @Mike completely agree with you